Is this homebrew "Summoner" class balanced, compared to the existing classes?
I found this summoner class on DMsGuild, and it seems like a fun, balanced class that fills an interesting niche.
I intend to play this character without multiclassing, using the Collector subclass, up to 10th level.
I asked a separate question about the balance of the Withhold Summon feature already. If my DM allows it, I'll probably play a Firemind Dragonborn for the permanent advantage on concentration checks.
Multiclassing

Ability Score Minimums: Int 13
Proficiencies: Calligrapher's tools, 1 skill from the summoner skill list.
Spell Slots: 2/3 of your summoner levels (rounded up)




Creating a Summoner

Hit points
Hit Dice. 1d6 per summoner level
Hit Points at 1st Level: 6 + your Constitution modifier
Hit Points at Higher Levels: 1d6 (or 4) + your Constitution modifier per summoner level after 1st
Proficiencies
Armor: None
Weapons: Daggers, darts, slings, quarterstaffs, light crossbows
Tools: Calligrapher's Tools
Languages: Any 3
Saving Throws: Intelligence, Wisdom
Skills: Skills: Choose three from Arcana, History, Religion, Nature, Animal Handling, Insight, Deception, Intimidation, Persuasion.
Starting Equipment:
You start with the following equipment, in addition to the equipment granted by your background:

any simple weapon of your choice
your choice of a component pouch or an arcane focus
your choice of a scholar's pack or a priest's pack
calligrapher's tools

If you forgo this starting equipment, as well as the items offered by your background, you start with 4d4 × 10 gp to buy your equipment.


Class Features:

As a summoner, you gain the following class features, which are summarized in the Summoner table.
Spellcasting
1st-level summoner feature
You have studied the occult arts and learned to draw
arcane and divine magic from the other planes of
existence, giving you the ability to cast spells to conjure
forth spirits and bend them to your will, as well as to
assist you in that purpose. See chapter 10 of the
Player’s Handbook for the general rules of spellcasting.
The summoner’s spell list can be found below.
Cantrips (0-level spells)
You know two cantrips of your choice from the
summoner spell list. At higher levels, you learn
additional summoner cantrips of your choice, as shown
in the Cantrips Known column of the Summoner table.
When you gain a level in this class, you can replace
one of the summoner cantrips you know with another
cantrip from the summoner’s spell list.
Preparing and Casting Spells
The Summoner table show how many spell slots you
have to cast your summoner spells. To cast one of your
summoner spells of 1st level or higher, you must
expend a slot of the spell’s level or higher. You regain all
expended spell slots when you finish a long rest.
You prepare the list of summoner spells that are
available for you to cast, choosing from the summoner
spell list. When you do so, choose a number of
summoner spells equal to your Intelligence modifier +
two-thirds your summoner level, rounded up. The spells
must be of a level for which you have spell slots.
For example, if you are a 5th-level summoner, you
have four 1st-level and three 2nd-level spell slots. With
an Intelligence of 14, your list of prepared spells can
include five spells of 1st or 2nd level, in any
combination. If you prepare the 1st-level spell unseen
servant, you can cast it using a 1st-level or a 2nd-level
slot. Casting the spell doesn’t remove it from your list of
prepared spells.
You can change your list of prepared spells when you
finish a long rest. Preparing a new list of summoner
spells requires time spent memorizing true names and
magical formulas: at least 1 minute per spell level for
each spell on your list.
Ritual Casting
You can cast a summoner spell as a ritual if that spell
has the ritual tag and you have the spell prepared.
Spellcasting Focus
You can use an arcane focus as a spellcasting focus for
your summoner spells.
Spellcasting Ability
Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for your
summoner spells; your understanding of the theory
behind magic allows you to wield these spells with
superior skill. You use your Intelligence whenever a
summoner spell refers to your spellcasting ability. In
addition, you use your Intelligence modifier when
setting the saving throw DC for a summoner spell you
cast and when making an attack roll with one.
Spell save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus +
your Intelligence modifier
Spell attack modifier = your proficiency bonus +
your Intelligence modifier
Summoner Spell List
Here’s the list of spells you consult when you learn or
prepare a summoner spell. The list is organized by spell
level, not character level. Spells indicate whether they
require concentration, are rituals, or summon creatures.
The book in which they can be found is also indicated
(see How to Use this Document). The Mad Leper
Presents ‒ The Summoner also contains new spells
in its last chapter.
 
Summoning Adept
1st-level summoner feature
You learn the bolster spirit cantrip and you always have
the summon monster spell prepared. Neither count
against the maximum number of cantrips you know or
against the number of spells you can prepare.
Additionally, when casting a spell with material
components that summons a creature, you halve the
spell’s cost in gp. The same applies to the material
components you provide when creating a spell scroll for
such a spell, but not for the creation of the scroll itself.
Mystic Callings
2nd-level summoner feature
In your study of otherworldly lore, you have unveiled
Mystic Callings, powerful enhancements to your
summoning magic.
Callings Known
When you gain this feature, you learn two mystic
callings of your choice, choosing from the “Mystic
Callings” section at the end of the class’s description.
You learn additional callings of your choice when you
reach certain levels in this class, as shown in the
Callings Known column of the Summoner table.
When you gain a level in this class, you can replace
one of the mystic callings you know with a new one.

As an action, you chant words of power and choose a
creature within 30 feet that was summoned by you,
imbuing the target with one of your mystic callings.
The creature remains imbued with the mystic calling
until it is killed or unsummoned. You can end the calling
early as a bonus action. It also counts as a spell-like
effect and can be dispelled as such.
A summoned creature can only be imbued by a single
mystic calling at a time. If you give it another calling, the
former calling is dispelled.
Some mystic callings require creatures to make
saving throws. The DC for those saves is the same as
your spell save DC.
Summoner Discipline
3rd-level summoner feature
Choose a specific discipline to pursue: Binder,
Collector, or Thaumaturgist, each of which is detailed
after the class’s description. Your choice grants you
features immediately and at 6th level, 10th level, and
14th level.
Ability Score Improvement
4th-level summoner featurea
When you reach 4th level and again at 8th, 12th, 16th,
and 19th level, you can increase one ability score of
your choice by 2, or you can increase two ability scores
of your choice by 1. As normal, you can’t increase an
ability score above 20 using this feature.
Withhold Summon
5th-level summoner feature
At 5th level, you gain the ability to shunt into a pocket
dimension a summoned creature that is under your
control and within 30 feet of you, as a bonus action.
While shunted away in that fashion, the target is
incapacitated. It can breathe normally, doesn’t require
sustenance, and can take a short or long rest, assuming
it has sufficient time to do so. If the target was
summoned through a spell, the spell’s duration is
suspended until the creature is released.
As an action, you can release a shunted creature,
making it reappear in an empty space within 30 feet of
you. While there is no limit to the number of creatures
you can shunt away with this feature, any concentration
required must still be maintained.
When you complete a long rest, for each of the
creatures that are still shunted away, you must choose
between expending anew the resource that was used to
summon it or to lose the shunted creature. For example,
if a creature was summoned using the summon
monster spell by expending a 2nd-level spell slot, you
must expend a 2nd-level spell slot at the end of the long
rest to keep the creature shunted, or the spell is simply
lost. The same applies for creatures summoned through
other ways, such as with a class feature with a limited
number of uses.


Subclass: Collector

Collector
Some summoners revel in accumulating an assortment
of thralls in their service. Those summoners, sometimes
known as collectors, allocate more of their studies to
keep control over multiple summons at once through
the use of advanced shunting conjuration. They also
become adept at catching new minions through the use
of a special ritual.
You fancy yourself a collector. You aim to become the
best trainer of monsters by having the largest collection.
After all, what are foes if not future allies?
Seize Control
3rd-level Collector feature
Your excellence at conjuration magic enables you to
capture new spirits to add to your muster.
You can perform a special 1 hour ritual in the location
of a creature’s death that occurred no more than 1
minute before the start of the ritual. In place of a dead
creature, you can also target a creature indigenous to
another plane of existence that is willing and remains
within 5 feet of you for the duration of the ritual. Either
way, the creature’s CR must be no higher than your
proficiency bonus.
To accomplish the ritual, you also require special
incense and candles consumed by the ritual and worth a
number of gold pieces equal to 10 × the creature’s CR.
Once the ritual is complete, you gain the ability to call
upon that creature’s spirit through a special use of your
summon monster spell. When doing so, you ignore the
CR limitation of that spell, but you can’t call upon that
specific spirit until you complete a long rest. When
summoned, the spirit uses its original stat block.
Training Expertise
3rd-level Collector feature
Your experience in training magical beasts has given
you an edge with matters of improving relations with
creatures of all sort.
You gain proficiency with two of the following skills:
Animal Handling, Intimidation, Persuasion, and
Deception.
Additionally, choose two of the above skills with
which you are proficient. Your proficiency bonus is
doubled for any ability check you make that uses either
of the chosen skills.
Finally, when serving as an instructor to a training
creature (see rules for Downtime Activities from the
Player’s Handbook, Dungeon Master’s Guide and/or
Xanathar’s Guide to Everything), you reduce the
required time for the training by a number of
workweeks equal to your proficiency bonus.
With your DM’s approval, you can spend your own
downtime training one of your summons to teach it
skills appropriate to its capabilities.
Improved Shunt
6th-level Collector feature
You learn to use your dimensional shunting to free your mind for other endeavors.
You do not need to maintain concentration on summoned creatures while they are shunted into a pocket dimension using your Withhold Summon feature. Once you release such a summoned creature from its pocket dimension, however, you must start maintaining concentration again.
If a summoning spell provides you with more than one creature and at least one of them isn’t shunted into a pocket dimension, you have to maintain concentration on the spell. However, you gain the ability to shunt away any number of creatures summoned through the casting of a single spell as a bonus action, and to release any number of them as an action.
Throng of Allies
10th-level Collector feature
As an action, you can release at once all of the creatures
that are currently shunted in a pocket dimension with
your Withhold Summon and Improved Shunt features,
without having to maintain concentration for any of
them. However, each of the released creatures that
would otherwise require concentration is then released
at the end of its next turn, either freeing them or
dispelling them as would normally be the case.


Mystic Callings

Mystic Callings
Mystic callings are magical enhancements to
summoning magic, imbuing your summoned creatures
with additional traits and bonuses.
If a mystic calling has prerequisites, you must meet
them to learn it. You can learn the calling at the same
time you meet its prerequisites. You can’t learn a calling
more than once.
If a mystic calling specifies a type of target, a creature
must first meet that criteria or attempts to imbue it with
that mystic calling automatically fail.
Bulwark of the Conscript
Prerequisite: bolster spirit cantrip
When you cast bolster spirit on the target, you add your
spellcasting ability modifier to the number of temporary
hit points gained.
Composure of the Attendant
Prerequisite: bolster spirit cantrip
When you cast bolster spirit on the target, it gains a
bonus to its next saving throw equal to your spellcasting
ability modifier
Footfall of the Colossus
Prerequisite: 9th-level summoner
Target: large or larger
The target can move through the space of any creature
that is smaller than the target’s size. When it does so,
creatures that aren’t its allies must succeed on a
Strength saving throw or fall prone.
Form of the Specter
As an action, the target can become incorporeal until
the end of its next turn, enabling it to move through
other creatures and objects as if they were difficult
terrain. It takes 1d10 force damage if it ends its turn
inside an object.
Hand of the Devoted Custodian
Prerequisite: bolster spirit cantrip
When you cast bolster spirit on the target, you also receive the same amount of temporary hit points.
Hostility of the Enforcer
Prerequisite: bolster spirit cantrip
When you cast bolster spirit on the target, it gains a
bonus to its next weapon attack roll equal to your
spellcasting ability modifier.
Mantle of the Avatar
Prerequisite: 9th-level summoner
Target: at least one size larger than you
As an action, you can touch the target to merge into its
form. Until you leave it as an action, you are merged
within the target and cannot take any other action,
bonus action or reaction, with the exception of actions
required to give orders to any of your summons. While
you are merged in this fashion, you are invisible and
invulnerable to all damage, and you share the target’s
space. If the target is reduced to 0 hit points, you are
immediately separated from it and any excess damage
carries over to you.
Might of the Champion
The target adds a d4 to its melee weapon damage rolls.
This bonus damage die becomes a d8 when you reach
10th level in this class.
Mirage of the Impostor
A duplicate of the target appears, as if it was under the
effects of the mirror image spell. This mystic calling
ends if the duplicate is destroyed.
A second duplicate is created when you reach 10th
level in this class, and the mystic calling only ends when
both duplicates are destroyed.
Passageway of the Astral Seafarer
Prerequisite: 5th-level summoner, Collector feature
When using your Withhold Summon feature, you can
shunt away or release the target on your turn without
using an action or bonus action.
Respite of the Veteran
Prerequisite: 5th-level summoner, Collector feature
Whenever you shunt away the target using your
Withhold Summon feature, it can immediately benefit
from a short rest.
Shelter of the Cerebus
When you take damage from an attack while the target
is within 5 feet of you, it can use its reaction and
interpose itself to take half the damage you received,
giving you resistance against the damage that triggered
the reaction.
Talent of the Muse
The target gains a number of skill or tool proficiencies
of your choice equal to your spellcasting ability modifier.
Veil of the Ghost Hound
As an action, the target can become invisible until the end of its next turn.


Spells
Note: If the balance of these spells is questionable, notify me in the comments, and I can move it to a new question.

Bolster Spirit
Conjuration cantrip
Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 30 feet
Components: V, S
Duration: 1 minute
Classes: cleric, druid, summoner, warlock, wizard
You recite a magical formula while pointing a finger toward a creature that was magically summoned through a spell, class feature, or creature trait. The target gains 1d4 temporary hit points. Remaining temporary hit points are lost at the end of the spell.
At Higher Levels. The temporary hit points given by
this spell increase by 1d4 when you reach 5th level
(2d4), 11th level (3d4), and 17th level (4d4).


Summon Monster
1st-level conjuration
Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 30 feet
Components: V, S
Duration: Concentration, up to 1 minute
Classes: summoner, wizard
You call forth a monster spirit. It manifests in an
unoccupied space that you can see within range. This
corporeal form uses the stat block of a creature of CR
1/2 or less. The DM has the creatures’ statistics.
The creature is an ally to you and your companions.
In combat, the creature shares your initiative count, but
it takes its turn immediately after yours. It obeys your
verbal commands (no action required by you). If you
don’t issue any, it takes the Dodge action and uses its
move to avoid danger.
If the creature has any of the Spellcasting, Pact
Magic, or Innate Spellcasting features, you must expend
a spell slot of the appropriate level for any spell it casts,
while it must also expends its limited uses or spell slots.
At Higher Levels. When you cast this spell using a 2nd-level spell slot, you can summon a creature of CR 1 or less. If you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the CR increases by 1 for every two slot levels above the 2nd.


For clarity, there is no limit to how many times the character can perform Mystic Callings per day (or between long rests) -- am I reading that correctly?

@ValleyLad Yes, you are. The limit is 1 calling per creature, but the summoner can apply them as many times as they'd like.

There is an error in the spell table, summon greater demon is not from the PHB.

This is not balanced, this is broken
This has another problem than mere power balance: it is a one trick pony that will not play well. In my play experience as well as in that of others, managing too many minions is a chore and detracts from fun. This class can essentially do very little other then creating an ever-bigger stable of minons that you then need to manage.
Granted, the spell list is trying to address this and create some other options by adding a few "best-of" spells that are not just "summon another kind of creature" like healing spirit, misty step, dimension door, forcecage and teleport, but considering the overwhelming focus on just summoning stuff, these feel both a bit out of place, and considering that all the other features aim to bolster summons, are not going to change this fundamentally.
Unbalanced Exploits
For your main question, this class is not only unbalanced in regards to how it plays but also regarding power level. The main class is probably fine, but in combination with the Collector subclass, it is not. The main issues I see:
Seize control is broken. This allows you to use your Summon Monster spell to summon any kind of creature, provided you fought and killed it before.
Even ignoring special abilities, a CR 2 monster is a deadly encounter for a third level party -- a though fight that could well kill a character. Since Seize Control gets rid of the CR level ceiling based on your caster level, you could with some luck defeat one of them, and then have a monster fight along you that is more dangerous than anyone in your entire team. Note that you could get CR 2 monsters at level 3, because they fit into your Proficiency Bonus 2 ceiling.
But that is not even the main issue here. There is a reason polymorph does not allow you to create targets other than beasts: monsters have all kinds of insane special abilities that would be utterly unbalancing in the hand of player characters. Normally, the new Summon Monster spell introduced here has a safety valve in that the DM picks what you get, but with this feature, you can pick and choose yourself, and you over time can get anything up to CR6. Here is a nice selection of things you could get. Some highlights that come to mind:

How about a pixie, CR 1/4, that provides polymorph, while you are level 3?
How about getting a rust monster CR 1/2 and destroying metal vault doors with ease?
How about an intellect devourer, CR2, that can stun any creature that fails a DC 12 Intelligence save? Want to take out a CR 17 Goristo demon? No problem, they only have Int 6. you can even have the devourer Body Thief them and control their body.
How about a wererat, also CR2, that is immune to non-magical, unsilvered weapons and that most tier one opponets will not be able to hurt at all?
How about a unicorn, CR4, that can teleport you and your pals, but does not need any spellcasting feature for that. Teleport at level 7 is surely balanced, no?
How about an umber hulk, CR5, that allows you to tunnel wherever you want leaving a conveniently human-sized tunnel in its wake and allowing you to entirely ignore or change dungeon layouts?

And so on, you get the idea. Then, once you get to level 6, and get access to Improved Shunt, you can build a whole zoo of such monsters, like a bag of golf clubs, have them all in storage and pick the right tool for whatever challenge you might face. How is your DM going to avoid that? Never let you encounter any monsters with special abilities?
I'm not even getting into the Mystic Callings that after level 6 you can have on each creature stored, like the Passageway of the Astral Wayfarer which allows you to summon the a creature you shunted for free while casting a full other spell or making full other use of your action. Or Throng of Allies for nova actions during boss fights -- just build up a dozen monsters in shunt. Who cares if they are gone at the end of their first round, by then the opponent is long dead. There are many more issues.
This class is a quagmire of abuse and problems.

+1, esp. "managing too many minions is a chore and detracts from fun" -- so true!  And even if it is fun for the minion master, it can be tedious for everyone else.  Also, great last paragraph.
